# How to set different image size when in mobile mode

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, media-queries

So my site image sizes set perfectly for desktop but when in mobile mode they not responsive even though I use bootstrap they over float the display size .How can I set a different image size when in mobile mode? Same question in regards google maps template.I tried to set media queries but it did not work.

My CSS:

```
@media(max-width: 400px) {
    #himage{width:200px;}
}
```

Here is my code:

```
@extends ('master') 

@section('content') 

<div class="row" id="promotions"> 
    <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 40px; ">
        <h1 style="text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);color:white; font-weight: bold;">News feed</h1><br>  
        <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);color:white; font-weight: bold;">This month promotion:</h3><br> 
        <p class="homeintro ">Set of Rick & Morty Pop! figures for 30.00$ only!For details visit our <a class="shopp" href="{{ url('shop')}} " style="text-decoration: none;">Shop</a>. </p> <br> 
        <div class="col-md-6" id="himage" >  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/rc.jpg')}}" width="500" > 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6" style="margin-bottom:15px" id="himage" >  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/mr.jpg')}}" width="500"> 
        </div> <br> <br><br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="margin:10px;" id="himage"> 
            <p class="homeintro "> Rick & Morty posters for 15.00$ only! </p> <br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;" id="himage" >  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/rmpos.jpg')}}" width="500" > 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;" id="himage">  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/rmpos2.jpg')}}" width="500"> 
        </div> <br><br>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="margin:10px;" id="himage"> 
            <h3 style="text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);color:white; font-weight: bold;"> Soon in our store. </h3> <br><br>
            <p class="homeintro ">Spider-Man Homecoming action figures!  </a>. </p> <br><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;" id="himage">  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/sphome3.jpg')}}" width="500" > 
        </div> 
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" style="margin-bottom:20px;"id="himage" >  
            <img src="{{ asset('images/sphome.jpg')}}" width="500"> 
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>


@endsection
```

Comment: You can't have more than 1 element with the same ID. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id

Comment: you are setting width of the div not image and can't have multiple elements with same ID

Comment: @Bourne96   yes thanks you it worked.How about google template map, its not an image ,how can I fix the size?

Comment: Are we talking about iframe, just target iframe and change it's width and height

Comment: Don't use same id for all images and set the `max-width:100%` for image so the images will set in mobile view.

Comment: @Bourne96 how exactly do I do that?

Comment: if there is <iframe> , target that iframe with for example media query which will recude it's size when you resize the window, iframe{ width: 250px; height:250px;} that's without using media query
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    iframe{
        height:250px;
        width:250px;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

In Bootstrap 4, you should add the [`img-fluid` class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) to any images you want to resize responsively.

(In Bootstrap 3, use [`img-responsive`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#images) instead.)